# Cannot run winzip26.exe to install winzip on wine

Tags: wine

I have tried to run wine winzip26.exe but I have got the following error messages:

> 002d:err:ntdll:RtlLeaveCriticalSection section 0x32fce0 is not acquired
> 002d:err:ntdll:RtlLeaveCriticalSection section 0x32fce0 is not acquired
> 002d:err:ntdll:RtlLeaveCriticalSection section 0x32fce0 is not acquired
> 002d:err:ntdll:RtlLeaveCriticalSection section 0x32fce0 is not acquired
> 002d:err:ntdll:RtlLeaveCriticalSection section 0x32fd70 is not acquired
> 002d:err:winediag:SECUR32_initNTLMSP ntlm_auth was not found or is outdated. Make sure that ntlm_auth >= 3.0.25 is in your path. Usually, you can find it in the winbind package of your distribution.
> Could not find Wine Gecko. HTML rendering will be disabled.
> 002d:err:mshtml:create_document_object Failed to init Gecko, returning CLASS_E_CLASSNOTAVAILABLE

What can I do with this? I have installed wine-gecko x86_x64.msi with wine msiexec /i  and then the x86 msi too, but nothing works. Thy for any help!

Comment: Did you do what it said (install `ntlm_auth` with a version more than 3.0.25)? Also, why do you want winzip on Linux? Not a full answer, but if you just want a GUI unzipping tool on Linux, 7-Zip probably will be more than enough. WinZip is called WinZip... because... well, it is for Windows.

Comment: Hi! Thy for the reply. I am just getting know of linux system and try to use some of the applications I have used on windows. I know it is not the best way to learn the linux system, but for work I need some windows based applications so I must have the knowledge of wine and the handling its errors. This is why I have been trying to install winzip for example.. I will try the ntlm_auth install. Thy